# XSLT multiple string replacement with recursion

Tags: xslt, recursion, substring, tail-recursion

I have been attempting to perform multiple (different) string replacement with recursion and I have hit a roadblock.  I have sucessfully gotten the first replacement to work, but the subsequent replacements never fire.  I know this has to do with the recursion and how the with-param string is passed back into the call-template.  I see my error and why the next xsl:when never fires, but I just cant seem to figure out exactly how to pass the complete modified string from the first xsl:when to the second xsl:when.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string" select="." />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&#13;&#10;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '&#13;&#10;')" />
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&#13;&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, 'TXT')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '&#13;TXT')" />
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&#13;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Remember that XML normalization transform any sequence of characters `#xD` `#xA` into one `#xA`. Also check my full parameterized answer.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for what I believe is a better solution than the one currently accepted (explanation of this at the end of my answer). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation is fully parameterized and doesn't need any tricks with default namespaces**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:params xml:space="preserve">
  <pattern>
   <old>&#xA;</old>
   <new><br/></new>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
   <old>quick</old>
   <new>slow</new>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
   <old>fox</old>
   <new>elephant</new>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
   <old>brown</old>
   <new>white</new>
  </pattern>
 </my:params>

 <xsl:variable name="vPats"
      select="document('')/*/my:params/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="multiReplace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pPatterns" select="$vPats"/>

  <xsl:if test=
   "string-length($pText) >0">

    <xsl:variable name="vPat" select=
     "$vPats[starts-with($pText, old)][1]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not($vPat)">
       <xsl:copy-of select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$vPat/new/node()"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
       "substring($pText, 1 + not($vPat) + string-length($vPat/old/node()))"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when it is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>The quick
brown fox</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
The slow<br/>white elephant
```

**Explanation**:

The text is scanned from left to right and at any position, if the remaining string starts with one of the specified patterns, then the starting substring is replaced by the replacement specified for the firat matching patterns.

**Do note**: If we have search patterns:

```
   "relation"   --> "mapping" 
   "corelation" --> "similarity"
```

in the above order, and text:

```
   "corelation"
```

then this solution produces the more correct result:

```
"similarity"
```

and the currently accepted solution by @Alejandro) produces:

```
"comapping"
```

**Edit**: With a small update we get another improvement: If at a given location more than one replace is possible, we perform the longest replace.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <my:params xml:space="preserve">
        <pattern>
            <old>&#xA;</old>
            <new><br/></new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>quick</old>
            <new>slow</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>fox</old>
            <new>elephant</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>brown</old>
            <new>white</new>
        </pattern>
    </my:params>

    <xsl:variable name="vrtfPats">
     <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/my:params/*">
      <xsl:sort select="string-length(old)"
           data-type="number" order="descending"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vPats" select=
     "ext:node-set($vrtfPats)/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pPatterns" select="$vPats"/>
        <xsl:if test=    "string-length($pText) >0">      
            <xsl:variable name="vPat" select=
            "$vPats[starts-with($pText, old)][1]"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($vPat)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$vPat/new/node()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                "substring($pText,
                          1 + not($vPat) + string-length($vPat/old/node())
                          )"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thus, if we have two reps such as "core" --> "kernel" and "corelation" --> "similarity", The second would be used for a text containing the word "corelation", regardless of how the reps are ordered.

Comment: +1 This is also a valid approach with sequencely searching. Although it still has the problem with respect to namespaces declaration: actual output is `The slow<br xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my" />white elephant`. Of course, with external documents both solution will have no problem.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I imagine that the actual use will always involve setting the params from outside, and thus didn't even bother explaining this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very thorough explanation and example.  I must admit though that this approach is somewhat above my needs, but I will certainly referrence this for my future needs.  As a side note, I have only been toying with XSLT for about 2 weeks now and am beginning to grasp how powerful XSLT truly is especially when coupled with superb mentors such as yourelf.  Again, Thank you for taking the time to teach those willing to learn.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev This was working fine for smaller xml files but now I realized it it throwing stack overflow exception in .Net.
The solution provided by user357812 seems to have no problem.

Comment: @Penko, Some, if not all XSLT 1.0 processors don't support tail-recursion and can crash with SO on long inputs. The second solution doesn't crash (yet) because its step is not a single character, but everything up to the next occurrence. However, the second solution doesn't handle well overlapping search patterns (see my comments about this), and would still crash on longer inputs. One can use a DVC (Divide and Conquer approach as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360310/print-numbers-from-one-to-one-million , however splitting is a little bit tricky here.

Comment: @Penko. You can split the text on smaller pieces (on a well-known character (like "." or " ") that is guaranteed not to be part of any of the search patterns, and apply the replacement on all pieces -- then concatenate them. This character cannot be universal, so it is reasonable to supply it as a parameter to the template that is called.

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet shows a verbose solution just for you to learn the pattern:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="string()"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSearch" select="'THIS'"/>
        <xsl:param name="pReplace" select="'THAT'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pString, '&#xA;')">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param
                         name="pString"
                         select="substring-before($pString, '&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <br/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param
                         name="pString"
                         select="substring-after($pString, '&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pString, $pSearch)">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param
                         name="pString"
                         select="substring-before($pString, $pSearch)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pReplace"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param
                         name="pString"
                         select="substring-after($pString, $pSearch)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<t>THIS is a test.
But THAT is not.
THIS is also a test.</t>
```

Output:

```
<t>THAT is a test.<br />But THAT is not.<br />THAT is also a test.</t>
```

**EDIT**: Full parameterized solution.

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <param name="pMap">
        <s t="&#xA;" xmlns=""><br/></s>
        <s t="THIS" xmlns="">THAT</s>
    </param>
    <template match="node()|@*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="text()" name="replace">
        <param name="pString" select="string()"/>
        <param name="pSearches"
                   select="document('')/*/*[@name='pMap']/s"/>
        <param name="vMatch" select="$pSearches[contains($pString,@t)][1]"/>
        <choose>
            <when test="$vMatch">
                <call-template name="replace">
                    <with-param
                         name="pString"
                         select="substring-before($pString, $vMatch/@t)"/>
                </call-template>
                <copy-of select="$vMatch/node()"/>
                <call-template name="replace">
                    <with-param
                         name="pString"
                         select="substring-after($pString, $vMatch/@t)"/>
                </call-template>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <value-of select="$pString"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<t>THAT is a test.<br/>But THAT is not.<br/>THAT is also a test.</t>
```

**Note**: There is a problem when using inline data in XML 1.0: you can't reset prefixed namespace declaration as in XML 1.1. The solution is to use a not common but valid notation: declare XSLT namespace as default namespace.

Comment: Very big thank you.. I just couldn't seem to wrap my head around what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Alejandro: I believe that it is more correct if not the first of the patterns that is contained in the string is replaced, but that the pattern that is found at the left-most position should be replaced. Thus if we have: "relation" --> "mapping" and "corelation" --> "similarity", and relation precedes "corelation" in the sequence of patterns, then your solution produces "comapping" while my solution produces "similarity".

Comment: @Dimitre: Those are two valid but differents approach, mine with "precedence" and yours sequencely.

Comment: @Alejandro: I believe that doing the replacements on a first come first serve basis in the input -- is the right one.

Comment: @Alejandro: I edited my solution and now not only it applies the replacements from left to right, but at any location in this process it always replaces the longest pattern found. This is the solution that best matches the real use-case for multiple replacements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may stem from differences in the encoding of newline, causing the XSLT processor not to recognize the CRLF in your match strings. I suggest testing with using comma in place of newline. The following will give you the expected result when called with the parameter "abc,def,ghi":

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="string" select="." />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string, ',')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, ',')" />
        <br/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, ',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the Dimitrie answer to put his solution in a template and using an exsl extension. Please check it, may be can be useful for someone.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:a="http://www.tralix.com/cfd/2" 
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="replacesList">
            <replaces>
                <replace><old>01</old><new>01 - Efectivo</new></replace>
                <replace><old>02</old><new>02 - Cheque nominativo</new></replace>
                <replace><old>03</old><new>03 - Transferencia electrónica de fondos</new></replace>
                <replace><old>04</old><new>04 - Tarjeta de Crédito</new></replace>
                <replace><old>05</old><new>05 - Monedero Electrónico</new></replace>
                <replace><old>06</old><new>06 - Dinero electrónico</new></replace>
                <replace><old>08</old><new>08 - Vales de despensa</new></replace>
                <replace><old>28</old><new>28 - Tarjeta de Débito</new></replace>
                <replace><old>29</old><new>29 - Tarjeta de Servicio</new></replace>
                <replace><old>99</old><new>99 - Otros</new></replace>
            </replaces>
        </xsl:variable>     
        <descripcionMetodoDePago>
            <xsl:call-template name="replaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replaces">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($replacesList/*/*)"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </descripcionMetodoDePago>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="replaces">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replaces"/>
        <xsl:if test="$text!=''">
            <xsl:variable name="replace" select="$replaces/*[starts-with($text, old)][1]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($replace)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="substring($text,1,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$replace/new/node()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="replaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select=
                "substring($text, 1 + not($replace) + string-length($replace/old/node()))"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replaces" select="$replaces"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Six years on, and in response to Alexander's comment, I decided to revisit the code and see if ChatGPT could help in making it tail-recursive. After a few (only partially successful) attempts to generate a working version, finally ChatGPT responded with (emphasis mine):

> Thank you for providing the output. I see that the issue of
> duplication still persists. Apologies for the inconvenience caused. I
> will make the necessary adjustments to the XSLT stylesheet to resolve
> this issue. *Please allow me a moment to update the stylesheet.*

Needless to say I'm still waiting for the updated stylesheet .

That said, the suggested changes were enough for me to be able to create a new version, which I present here. If the input XML is large enough, it will probably still overflow (I was able to process ~20Mb XML files in an old version of Stylus Studio (v2009), but your mileage may vary :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:dps="dps:dps">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="vPatterns">
        <dps:patterns>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;i&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;em&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;/i&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;/em&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;b&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;strong&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;/b&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;/strong&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
        </dps:patterns>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vPats" select="exsl:node-set($vPatterns)/dps:patterns/*"/>

    <!-- This template matches all text() nodes, and calls itself recursively to perform the actual replacements. -->
    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" select="''"/>

        <xsl:variable name="find" select="$vPats[$pos]/old"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replace" select="$vPats[$pos]/new"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Ignore empty strings -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length(translate(normalize-space($text), ' ', '')) = 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- Return the unchanged text if the replacement is larger than the input (so no match possible) -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length($find) &gt; string-length($text)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($result, $text)"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- If the current text contains the next pattern -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $find)">
                <!-- Perform a recursive call, each time replacing the next occurrence of the current pattern -->
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$find)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="result" select="concat($result, substring-before($text, $find), $replace)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- No (more) matches found -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Bump the counter to pick up the next pattern we want to search for -->
                <xsl:variable name="next" select="$pos+1"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- If we haven't finished yet, append the remaining text (if any),
                         and make a recursive call with the accumulated result. -->
                    <xsl:when test="boolean($vPats[$next])">
                        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="concat($result, $text)"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$next"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="result" select="''"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <!-- No more patterns, we're done. Return the fully processed text. -->
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($result, $text)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

***Original reply***

Although this question was asked (and answered) several years ago, neither this answer nor the (many!) other variants I found while searching the 'net over the last couple of days were able to do what I needed: replace multiple strings in nodes which may contain several *kb* of text.

Dimitre's version works well when nodes contain very little text, but when I tried to use it I almost immediately fell foul of the dreaded stack overflow (recursive calls, remember!) The problem with Dimitre's solution is that it tries to match the search patterns to the beginning of the text. This means that many (recursive) calls are made, each call using the right-most n-1 characters of the original text. For a 1k text that means over 1000 recursive calls!

After digging around for alternatives I came across an example by Ibrahim Naji (http://thinknook.com/xslt-replace-multiple-strings-2010-09-07/) which uses the more conventional substring-before/substring-after combination to perform the replacement. However, that code is limited to a single replacement string for any number of search strings.

I decided, therefore, that it was time to actually get my hands dirty (and learn XSLT at the same time!) The result is the following code which performs multiple string replacements (specified via an internal template, but that could easily be replaced with an external file, for example), and which (so far in my tests) doesn't suffer from excessive recursive calls.

It should be noted that the replacements are very basic (as are most other existing implementations) meaning that no attempts are made to only match entire words, for example. I hope the comments are enough to explain the way it works, particularly for other XSLT beginners (like myself).

And now the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:dps="dps:dps">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!--
        The original version of this code was published by Ibrahim Naji (http://thinknook.com/xslt-replace-multiple-strings-2010-09-07/).
        It works but suffered the limitation of only being able to supply a single replacement text. An alternative implementation, which
        did allow find/replace pairs to be specified, was published by Dimitre Novatchev
        (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213644/xslt-multiple-string-replacement-with-recursion).
        However, that implementation suffers from stack overflow problems if the node contains more than a few hundred bytes of text (and
        in my case I needed to process nodes which could include several kb of data). Hence this version which combines the best features
        of both implementations.

        John Cullen, 14 July 2017.
     -->

    <!-- IdentityTransform, copy the input to the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process all text nodes. -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Table of replacement patterns -->
    <xsl:variable name="vPatterns">
        <dps:patterns>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;i&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;em&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;/i&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;/em&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;b&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;strong&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old>&lt;/b&gt;</old>
                <new>&lt;/strong&gt;</new>
            </pattern>
        </dps:patterns>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--
        Convert the internal table into a node-set. This could also be done via a call to document()
        for example select="document('')/*/myns:params/*" with a suitable namespace declaration, but
        in my case that was not possible because the code is being used in with a StreamSource.
     -->
    <xsl:variable name="vPats" select="exsl:node-set($vPatterns)/dps:patterns/*"/>

    <!-- This template matches all text() nodes, and calls itself recursively to performs the actual replacements. -->
    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replace" select="$vPats[$pos]/old"/>
        <xsl:variable name="by" select="$vPats[$pos]/new"/>
        <xsl:choose>

            <!-- Ignore empty strings -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length(translate(normalize-space($text), ' ', '')) = 0"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- Return the unchanged text if the replacement is larger than the input (so no match possible) -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length($replace) > string-length($text)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- If the current text contains the next pattern -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <!-- Perform a recursive call, each time replacing the next occurrence of the current pattern -->
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="concat(substring-before($text,$replace),$by,substring-after($text,$replace))"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- No (more) matches found -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Bump the counter to pick up the next pattern we want to search for -->
                <xsl:variable name="next" select="$pos+1"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- If we haven't finished yet, perform a recursive call to process the next pattern in the list. -->
                    <xsl:when test="boolean($vPats[$next])">
                        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$next"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <!-- No more patterns, we're done. Return the fully processed text. -->
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was happy to find and try your advance on Ibrahim Naji's multireplace. Unfortunately I still run into the same infinite recursions in my case :(

Comment: Though I have to add there seems to be *some* improvement :)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderRutz, I just posted an updated version which you might want to try out.