# How to simulate xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

Any ideas how to simulate

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
```

in XSLT 1.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="foreach">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="10"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="foreach">
        <xsl:param name="i"/>
        <xsl:param name="n"/>

        <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $n">
            <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="foreach">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Oh my, that looks quite complicated. I just wanted to have a small bit of layout duplicated 3 times, without violationg DRY principle. I don't want to trade DRY for KISS though :)

Comment: @VoodooRider, Well, I think in XSLT 1.0 you need to duplicate your code or put code in named template and call it 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

@Kirill has provided the "standard answer".

**While it is correct, it has one practical problem** -- for large values of `N`, at least on some XSLT processors, this transformation crashes painfully -- due to stack overflow.

There is a way to perform such transformations for very big N normally, without stack overflow -- **on all XSLT processors**.

Read more about the DVC (Divide and Conquer) recursion in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360310/print-numbers-from-one-to-one-million/4360693#4360693)**.

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers your stylesheet or your input document is probably having enough nodes to simply process e.g. three nodes

```
<xsl:for-each select="//node()[position() &lt; 4]">
  <!-- now output stuff here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```