# XSLT 1.0 Loop based on XML value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to use XSLT to print a barcode label a specific number of times based on the value of an XML tag that's being passed to it.
For example, if the XML has a Quantity value of 10, I'd like to apply the template multiple times so that a barcode is created for each item.

At the moment, I already have things working to where it'll print out a single tag, but I'm getting stuck trying to sort out how to get it to apply multiple times based off of the XML.

Below is the latest bit I tried; I was attempting to set a variable based on the XML and then loop based on the variable.  My understanding is that there are ways to apply a template based on the number of matching nodes in an XML file, but since each XML file would just have one Quantity node in this case, I don't think that method will work.

I apologize that I'm likely doing quite a bit wrong here; I'm fairly new to XSLT. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<xsl:template match="//Order/OrderLine">
<xsl:param name="var" select="..//Order/OrderLine/Product/Properties/Quantity/"/>
  <xsl:if test="$var &gt; 0">
                 
    <!-- code to create barcode label would be here-->
  
    <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="//Order/OrderLine">
        <xsl:with-param name="var" select="$var - 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646731/how-to-simulate-xslfor-each

Comment: More info on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076323/xslt-looping-from-1-to-60