# how to iterate to print nos of given length in xslt?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Im working on xslt 1.0
I need to print nos starting from 1 to given length.

e.g. if the given length is 5, then i need to iterate a loop that can iterate 5 times and prints nos like 1,2,3,4,5 this.
I tried using for loop but, I'm unable to decrement the value to print in each iterator.

Please any suggestion on above scenario?
Thanks inadvanvce

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="printNumbers">
      <xsl:with-param name="pUpTo" select="5"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="printNumbers">
      <xsl:param name="pUpTo"/>
      <xsl:param name="pCurrent" select="1"/>

      <xsl:if test="$pUpTo >= $pCurrent">
        <xsl:value-of select="$pCurrent"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

        <xsl:call-template name="printNumbers">
          <xsl:with-param name="pUpTo" select="$pUpTo"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pCurrent" select="$pCurrent+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

For successfully generating huge number of items, use a DVC - style recursion as in my answer to this question:

**[Print numbers from one to one million](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360310/print-numbers-from-one-to-one-million)**

I recommend using the functions of the **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** library in order to avoid spending too much time in writing explicit recursion and also to avoid any potential errors doing this.